# How to move a project from one team to another team in bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I have an account on bitbucket where two teams are present. Inside one team I have a project. Now I want to move that project into another team.
Can anyone tell me that it's possible to do so. If yes, please tell me the procedure.

Thanks..!!

Comment: have you managed to do it? I have the same scenario.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a project with empty repo within the new team in Bitbucket.
2. Clone the original project locally (assuming "origin" for the remote name):

   `git clone <url>`
3. In you local repo, add a new remote for the new project repo (assuming "neworigin" for the remote name) and fetch from it:

   `git remote add neworigin <url>`
   `git fetch neworigin`
4. Push everything from the original project (origin) to the new one (neworigin) with :

   `git push neworigin +refs/remotes/origin/\*:refs/heads/\*`
   `git push --tags neworigin`